# Using .php parsed as javascript source, how to wrap javascript code between php brackets using conditionals

Tags: php, javascript, parsing

Currently i'm working on a project which requires dynamical content parsed using some simple javascript functions, which i need to load depending on which 'view' is currently using a given user.

I'm having issues using something like this on a .js or .php file:

** .php file that calls javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="*.js/.php"  />
```

** .js file

```
<?php header(Content-type: 'application/javascript'); ?>

alert('this shows correctly);

<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['view']) { 
          if($_REQUEST['view']=='private_view') { ?> 

            var xname = <?php echo $_SESSION['x']; ?>
            //Array stuff filled from MySQL queries.
<?php } ?>

<?php     if($_REQUEST['view']=='public_view') { ?> 

            var other_variable = <?php echo $xxx; ?>
            $(element).functions();
<?php } ?>
```

The php code i'm using works correctly, already tested it. I'm also convinced that there are other ways to work this around, like using different files and choosing them with a conditional right on .php where I define script call, but i'm so curious about why this isn't working.

I'm used to work like this wrapping HTML content between brackets, to hide or show depending on given conditions.

The output of this will be only alert call, no PHP error/warning/notification,

I can't seem to find a correct way to do this, have been searching for a while but only find how to parse .js as php modifying .htaccess file.

Comment: This seems bad design overall, for maintainability concerns first of all, though we should see more of the js code to tell.

Comment: Already changed example a bit, I got this working using echo '$(element).functions('.$var.');'; for every line of code in javascript, but is that the only way to do this?.

Answer (score 2):

You should simply rename the `.js` file to a `.php` file.

Comment: Already tried that, forgot to mention I already added .htaccess which allows to parse .js files as php.